# Android Studio: Read timed out for "dl.google.com"

Tags: android-studio, connectivity

I currently cannot setup my Android Studio since it seems not to be able to download packages from google, particularly from "https://dl.google.com/...".

Details:

- Updating the IDE, download SDKs, etc. does not work and ends in a "Read timed out" error
- According to the idea.log file, it looks like this

```
2022-12-30 08:19:42,842 [ 132503]   INFO - er.configure.SourcesTableModel - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml 
2022-12-30 08:19:43,143 [ 132804]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml 
2022-12-30 08:21:02,106 [ 211767]   INFO - er.configure.SourcesTableModel - IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml 
2022-12-30 08:21:02,106 [ 211767]   INFO - er.configure.SourcesTableModel - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out 
2022-12-30 08:21:02,417 [ 212078]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml 
2022-12-30 08:21:02,418 [ 212079]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

- The file IS accessible from within my regular browser
- I do not require any proxy, nor there is any proxy set up in my network setup
- If I go to Setting > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy and do "Check Connection"

  - it perfectly works for "https://www.google.com"
  - but it does NOT work for "https://dl.google.com"

Does anyone have an idea what that could be? Android Studio behaves as if it would deal differently with this domain AND/OR "dl.google.com" acts differently for the built-in HTTPS client in contrast to a regular browser.

I tried

- Uninstalling/Reinstalling various versions of Android Studio (-> same issue)

  - I also made sure that there are no leftovers of any configuration between the different versions
  - I also removed anything that has to do with gradle
- Accessing the domain from within different browsers (-> no issue at all)
- Deactivated the Windows firewall (-> same issue)
- Started Android Studio with administrator privileges